# Question about Vandermonde matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let

$A_n = \begin{pmatrix}1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \dots &{x_1}^{n-1} \\1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \dots & {x_2}^{n-1} \\\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \dots &{x_n}^{n-1}  \\\end{pmatrix}$
We know that $det(A_n)=\prod_{1 \leq j < i \leq n} (x_i-x_j)$.

In case of  $n=3$

$A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & x_1  &{x_1}^{2} \\1 & x_2  &{x_2}^{2}  \\ 1 & x_3  &{x_3}^{2}  \\\end{pmatrix}$

However I get something entirely different when applying Sarrus. With Sarrus I get $x_2*{x_3}^2+x_1*{x_2}^{2}+{x_1}^{2}*{x_3}-{x_1}^2*x_2-x_1*{x_3}^2-{x_2}^{2}*x_3$

when applying the given formula $det(A_3)=\prod_{1 \leq j < i \leq 3} (x_i-x_j)=(x_3-x_2)(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_1)$

I do not know whether I applied the product with the indices correctly. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Your approach just lacks some algebraic manipulations.

According to the Sarrus' method, we have:
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_{1} & x^{2}_{1}\\
1 & x_{2} & x^{2}_{2}\\
1 & x_{3} & x^{2}_{3}
\end{vmatrix} & = x_{2}x^{2}_{3} + x_{1}x^{2}_{2} + x^{2}_{1}x_{3} - x^{2}_{1}x_{2} - x_{1}x^{2}_{3} - x^{2}_{2}x_{3}\\\\
& = (x_{2}x^{2}_{3} - x^{2}_{2}x_{3}) + (x_{1}x^{2}_{2} - x^{2}_{1}x_{2}) + (x^{2}_{1}x_{3} - x_{1}x^{2}_{3})\\\\
& = x_{2}x_{3}(x_{3} - x_{2}) + x_{1}x_{2}(x_{2} - x_{1}) + x_{1}x_{3}(x_{1} - x_{3})\\\\
& = x_{2}x_{3}(x_{3}-x_{2}) + x_{1}x_{2}(x_{2} - x_{3}) + x_{1}x_{2}(x_{3} - x_{1}) + x_{1}x_{3}(x_{1} - x_{3})\\\\
& = (x_{2}x_{3} - x_{1}x_{2})(x_{3} - x_{2}) + (x_{1}x_{2} - x_{1}x_{3})(x_{3} - x_{1})\\\\
& = x_{2}(x_{3} - x_{1})(x_{3} - x_{2}) + x_{1}(x_{2} - x_{3})(x_{3} - x_{1})\\\\
& = (x_{2} - x_{1})(x_{3} - x_{1})(x_{3} - x_{2})
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thsnk you so much for your explanation

Comment: @Inocenciaa You are welcome ! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You have applied Sarrus incorrectly, unless there is a typo. There should be a "wrap-around" effect. The $x_1^2$ should be $x_1^2\cdot x_3$. The other issue is that you need to factor the expression that you have found to make it match the Vandermonde determinant's standard formula. Also, you made another typo where it should have been $$(x_3 - x_2)(x_2 -x_1)(x_3-x_1).$$

Comment: thank you for your answer, those were in fact only typos and I have corrected them. However I unfortunately still do not understand how to show that they are equal, when multiplying the parentheses, I also get a part with $x_1 x_2 x_3$ which I never get with Sarrus.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the first line from the others and then subtract the second from the third line we get
\begin{align*}
     \det\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2\\1&y&y^2\\1&z&z^2
     \end{bmatrix}&=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2\\0&y-x&y^2-x^2\\0&z-x&z^2-x^2\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2\\0&y-x&(y-x)(y+x)\\0&z-x&(z-x)(z+x)\end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2\\0&y-x&y^2-x^2\\0&z-x&z^2-x^2\end{bmatrix}\\
&=(y-x)\det\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2\\0&1&y+x\\0&z-x&(z-x)(z+x)\end{bmatrix}\\&=(y-x)(z-x)\det\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2\\0&1&y+x\\0&1&z+x
     \end{bmatrix}\\
&=(y-x)(z-x)\det\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2\\0&1&y+x\\0&0&z-y
    \end{bmatrix}=(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)
    \end{align*}